# Pyarrow parquet can't read dataset with large metadata

Tags: metadata, pyarrow, petastorm

I used Petastorm `row_group_indexer` to build index for a column in a petastorm dataset. After that, the size of the metadata file increased significantly and Pyarrow can't load the dataset anymore due to this error:

```
OSError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: TProtocolException: Exceeded size limit
```

Here is the code I'm using to load the dataset:

```py
from pyarrow import parquet as pq

dataset_path = "path/to/dataset/"

dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(path_or_paths=dataset_path)
```

Code used for indexing the materialized petastorm dataset:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from petastorm.etl.rowgroup_indexers import SingleFieldIndexer
from petastorm.etl.rowgroup_indexing import build_rowgroup_index

dataset_url = "file:///path/to/dataset"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("demo").config("spark.jars").getOrCreate()

indexer = [SingleFieldIndexer(index_name="my_index",index_field="COLUMN1")]

build_rowgroup_index(dataset_url, spark.sparkContext, indexer)
```

Comment: Which version of pyarrow is installed? I think this might be fixed in pyarrow 6.0 (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13655, although the exact error message is a bit different)

Comment: I'm using latest version 6.0.0.

Comment: Can you open an issue at https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues to further discuss this?